Flutter Android Emulator Not Connecting to Company VPN for Host Lookup
I'm encountering a problem where the Android Emulator won't connect to my company's VPN, blocking access to our servers from the app I'm developing and resulting in a host lookup error. Despite trying solutions suggested by others on this site, the issue persists.
I'm using Windows 11 and FortiClient for the VPN.
My attempted solutions:

Initially, I managed to connect by adjusting the firewall to permit emulator traffic through the VPN. However, the emulator suddenly stopped connecting to the VPN even though the firewall settings were unchanged.
The server is functioning correctly since my colleague can access it.
Restarting the emulator, VSCode, and my computer didn't resolve the problem.


I have experienced the same situation before, contact your company's IT department. There may be a special rule in the VPN configuration that blocks emulator traffic.

I've called to the IT deparment and it seems that everything is the same like my colleague has it. Tried tinkering a bit with proxy but that doesn't work either.
